# Refresh context without refreshing configuration from file

Tags: spring

Is it possible to refresh context without refreshing configuration ?
I found method `ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh()` but it refresh configuration from file.
I would like to do below steps in runtime:

1. get context and bean
2. change bean property value
3. refresh context

Comment: If you have changed a bean prop in (2) why do you want to "refresh" the context? What do you hope to achieve by that?

Comment: Some beans (B1) are factories to other beans (B2). B1 have some values in properties which are passed to B2 (when B2 are created). I can change only props of B1 but in runtime I use B2.

Comment: Ok refreshing all context is not ok. I would like to change only B2 beans.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is slightly weird. Your factories THEMSELVES might be initialized from properties, so if you were to only 'refresh the context', without caring from where it came, your factories will REVERT themselves back to their initial state. Let's describe it like that.

```
1. Context Started
2. Factory initalized
3. Factory used to create beans
4. ..application running
5. You manually change a FACTORY prop that doesn't affect the factory, but a specific Bean. You want your bean refreshed. You think refreshing the context will do that for you
6. Boom, you refresh the context. Factories are reinitialized to their default values
7. Factories are used to create beans, which are the same beans in step 2, not the ones you would want in step 5, since the factories themselves are reverted to their default properties
```

What is the solution?

You can change your setup method. Whatever properties your factories pass to your child beans, you can just autowire in the child beans. Then, when you change those properties, they will be reflected in the child beans, so you wouldn't have to refresh your context. Simple, huh?

Comment: Yes, when I tried to use `refresh()` it behaved like you described in scenario. Configuration of context was refreshed so I lost changes. So I would like to re-create only chosen beans (in my case child beans). Your solution is ok if child bean classes are your. In my case these classes are external.